# Amplify sort property from a model

Tags: sorting, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm using graphql from amplify
I have a 2 models `Conversation` and `Message`.
`Message` model belongs to `Conversation` (conversation has many messages)
So when I get `Conversation` by some criteria I want my messages to be sorted based on created at property.
Is there a way to do that?